# How would one encode a cd as streaming wma (19kbs or 37kbs)?

Tags: streaming, ripping, audio-recording, cdex

I'm looking for either a way to shave time by direct encoding or a way to streamline the process further. Currently the method that I'm using is as follows.

1. Rip the track with CDex (cdexos.sourceforge.net) to a wav file.

   - (3-5min for 45 minutes +/-5)
2. Encode the wav as wma with Windows Media Encoder ver9

   - select streaming, select voice (19 kbs voice or 37kbs radio), and set properties.
   - (another 3-5min)
3. upload (add 2 min)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i much prefer [**Exact Audio Copy**](http://www.exactaudiocopy.de/) over CDex (for quality reasons, which don't seem to be of great concern in this case, considering the low bitrate).

and here's a guide from the nice folks at the HydrogenAudio forums: [**How to configure EAC to create WMA files**](http://www.hydrogenaudio.org/forums/lofiversion/index.php/t18402.html), using a Command Line Encoder written in VBscript (adjust the bitrate to your likings).

this will save you one step.

you can also use Windows Media player, but it requires a ['registry hack'](http://www.liutilities.com/products/registrybooster/tweaklibrary/tweaks/10390/) to use custom bitrates < 48kbps.

Comment: Thank You for the response, I've read through some of the documentation on 'Exact Audio Copy'.  I like some of its features, I will be experimenting with it tonight.

Comment: good choice, enjoy this truly outstanding CD ripper, although its talents seem to to be a bit wasted on 19kbps WMAs. but it can also do fast, not only quality :)